# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object while trying to list users

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to list usernames that are in a database but i get this error:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

The code for my search page is

```
$user = $_GET['u'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE '%". $user ."%'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['username'];

}

} else {


echo 'No Results';

}
```

And the code for my index page

```
 <form action="search.php" method="GET"><input type="text" name="u" placeholder="Username" required="" maxlength="14" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="nospaces(this)" style="background-color: white;border: 2px solid blue;border: none; padding: 6px 24px;">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Fixed by changing the database and switching to mysql instead of mysqli

Comment: Why you using $row before it's declared? i mean before the loop?

Comment: My mistake, fixed it now.

Comment: Are you still getting the error?

Comment: Yeah it still is telling me that

Comment: what does `var_dump( $result );` yield?

Comment: Output is string(6) "Tester"

Comment: try dumping the value of $row. and check what it's showing

Comment: I am getting NULL

Comment: Wait i didn't see undefined variable so that will be why i am getting NULL

Comment: Undefined variable row

Comment: Would you share "$conn" variable ? How are you initializing it ?

Comment: I managed to fix this by using mysql instead of mysqli and changed the database